# UserControl style - Unable to cast Style to Brush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I working on WPF application. I have user control with default style in `shared.xaml` and theme style (couple XAML files with different styles).

Problem is that I get message **Unable to cast object of type "System.Windows.Style" to type "System.Windows.Media.Brush"** 
and in user control shared style is included like this:

```
Style="{StaticResource statusBar}"
```

NOTE: When I remove this line no error and no style in the status bar (so the problem is in that style file).

**In shared.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="statusBar" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource StatusBarBackgroud}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource FontFamilyStatusBar}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundStatusBar}"/>
</Style>
```

Problem is **Foreground** (in LightTheme.xaml where shared file point on it)

```
<Style x:Key="ForegroundStatusBar" >
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="LightBlue" />  
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foreground` property is of type Brush. you cannot assign `{DynamicResource ForegroundStatusBar}` there, when ForegroundStatusBar resource is `Style`. If foreground should be inherited from base style, use BasedOn parameter in a derived Style

```
<Style x:Key="statusBar" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ForegroundStatusBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource StatusBarBackgroud}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource FontFamilyStatusBar}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <!--Foreground setter removed-->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<Style x:Key="ForegroundStatusBar"
   TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
</Style>
```